# Suggestions for showing instant updates of db tables on a chart using asp.net mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

I am planning to develop a web app that will show conditions of environments. My service reads from sensors and writes them in a database. Service reads at a 1-minute interval. Whenever a value change happens I will show it on a chart in an aps.net MVC app.

Any suggestions for a library or a design pattern will be appreciated. I searched online and SignalR may be used for this, however it seems like a little bit complicated.

Comment: SignalR is probably the best fit for your scenario. Once you follow tutorials, practice a bit and try to implement it, it won't seem quite so complicated (just like anything in life, really). If communication is purely one way (server to browser) then you might be able to get away with using Server-Sent Events (SSE) which is potentially a bit less complicated (although I don't know if any ready-made .NET implementations exist in the way that SignalR does for websockets, you'd have to search). The least optimal solution is using AJAX to poll the server from the client.

Comment: @ADyson thank you very much for your help and time. I am interested in using AJAX calls. What will be the best choice for using the AJAX call? Will I be needing web API for using AJAX calls?

Comment: Why do you want to use Ajax calls for this? I mentioned it as an option, but only as a last resort if, for some reason, you cannot use websockets or server sent events. Both those solutions will be more efficient...you should look into them before you fall back on the Ajax solution

Comment: @ADyson  I just saw a couple of tutorials on SignalR and it seems a little complicated to me that's why I prefer to use AJAX. And I am not sure if there is a PostgreSQL tutorial on signalr since I have to connect it.

Comment: The way you connect to databases is the same across all types of .NET application whether it's SignalR, MVC, winforms, console app or whatever. So that part should not be a problem. As for it being "difficult", see my first comment. Ajax is not always straightforward to get right either, if you're not very familiar with it. Plus, SignalR is useful and you'll soon think of ways you can use it in other applications, so it's worth investing some time to learn it. If you give up without really trying every time something looks a bit tricky, then you won't get very far as a programmer.

Comment: Try it out. If you get stuck on some particular details when you are attempting to implement it, then you can ask a question about it here - those are our favourite kind of questions, where someone is trying to solve their issue but is just stuck on a specific area, and we can help them debug and fix it. We like answering those :-)

Comment: @ADyson thank you so much for your encouraging comments. I will definitely go with SignalR. The last question, I mostly see tutorials of SignalR on .net core, is that ok it to use with .net framework?

Comment: No, there might be some differences. If you are using .NET framework then it would be better to find specific instructions for that. SignalR is compatible with both.

Comment: @ADyson Thank you again so much for your time and help.